# Select by fixed categories top result and rest in others

Tags: mysql, sql, database, group-by, count

On the begging Im gonna say that I can't change any structure of database, only select is allowed.
I thought about this about 1 week and can't find solution for my problem.

Lets assume I have table like this: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cEbW3ZoQBRpun3Pt5g3h3v/1
There I have products with their categories and I'd to make report which show me how much there is product in X category and select TOP 3 with count and others display in "Others" with all other count. But some categories should be count together (I'd like to predefined them in select query), for example I'd have A count with G and B-C, E-F.

So result should looks like:

```
B-C = 7
A-G = 6
D = 5
OTHERS = 6
```

Tell me, it's even possible with just select, if yes please tell me how (example would be nice) if not I'm gonna tell this to my manager because RN he won't believe me saying "you can do it".

Comment: I think you mean 'going to'

Comment: You can `left join` the table with itself multiple times and define the condition in the `join clause` for every type of category.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would approach this with a derived table that represents the mapping between categories, that the original table can be `left join`ed with. You can then aggregate, which gives you the count of product for each of these "real" categories. Then, you can use window functions (available in MySQL 8.0 only) and an additional level of aggregation to separate the top 3 from the rest of the "real" categories.

```
select 
    case when rn <= 3 then real_category else 'Other' end final_category,
    sum(no_products) no_products
from (
    select 
        coalesce(x.new_category, p.category) real_category, 
        count(*) no_products,
        rank() over(order by count(*) desc) rn
    from products p
    left join (
        select 'A' category, 'A-G' new_category
        union all select 'G', 'A-G'
        union all select 'B', 'B-C'
        union all select 'C', 'B-C'
        union all select 'E', 'E-F'
        union all select 'F', 'E-F'
    ) x on x.category = p.category
    group by real_category
) t
group by final_category
order by no_products desc
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=22b3b6948bbe3135fba71e0e55c19b49)**:

```
final_category | no_products
:------------- | ----------:
A-G            |           6
B-C            |           6
D              |           5
Other          |           5
```